# SQL Server 2012 32-bit or 64-bit on 64-bit machine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, 32bit-64bit

I'm about to install SQL Server 2012 Developer on my 64-bit machine for developing purposes, but I'm not sure if I should install the 32-bit or 64-bit version.

My confusion comes from the fact that my Visual Studio 2012 is 32-bit and my laptop is not quite fast (Intel Core2Duo P8400 @ 2.26Ghz with 5GB RAM).

Generally speaking 64-bit or 32-bit app installation on 64-bit machine is the right choice?

Answer (score 7):

The default solution to all SQL Server performance problems is to throw more memory at it. That only works above 4GB if you have 64 bit SQL Server on a 64 bit machine. You already have a 64 bit machine with more than 4GB memory therefore installing the 64 bit version of SQL Server is a no brainer.

Note that it doesn't matter if you don't have to support a very large database at the time you have to make the decision because you don't know what the future will bring. I have had exactly that experience and am now really glad that at the time I installed the 64 bit version and now am working with a 50+GB database. Something I didn't anticipate at the time.

Answer (score 4):

There is no general advice which version to install. Visual Studio runs in a 32bit process, but your project can target 64bit because it will be debugged within another process.

The main question is: How much RAM do you think your database will need? There aren't any drawbacks on installing 64bit software on 64bit machines, but 32bit software will be executed on a compatibility layer (WoW64 - windows on windows 64).

Using 32 or 64 bit software on old hardware makes no difference, either. As long as the processor supports it!

Comment: Thanks Matten for the quick answer! Are you saying I can install the 64-bit version without concerns?

Comment: Will the 32-bit version of SQL Server be able to load 64-bit assemblies for server-side components?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a thing as Visual Studio 64bit, VS only comes 32bit regardless the operating system and the project target, this is due to the fact that VS UI will execute different processes external tasks

As for SQL Microsoft instructions strongly recommend to install SQL 32bit versions only when running on a 32bit OS version.

So you should install 64bit version

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Some applications actually require 32 bit versions in order for them to run. So be sure if other applications will use the same SQL server that there is not a compatibility issue by going to 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, A 32 bit OS will allows the keep the RAM or utilize the RAM upto 2powe32 kb's. mean's the server will allows you the operation;s of memory upto 2power32 kbs ....similarly 64 bit..2powerof 64.

you can install a 32bit in 64 bit os..but you cannot install 64bit SQL Server in 32 bit OS